# Jquery .val() on a Object

Tags: jquery, dictionary

```
id = [<input type=​"hidden" name=​"id" value=​"test_id">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"id" value=​"test_id">​]
id.val()
Result: "test_id"
```

I have an "id object" with two HTML Elments. There are the same because I will update two identical Elements with one ajax get.

I got this variable "id" with a selector who search for a form.

**My Question:**

Is [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) checking both Elements or only the first Element in this object "id"?

And what is if one of the Elements has a different value.

**What I did after this question!**

- I'm using now [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get both values from the objct
- Added a check for the equality of the id's.
- Learned not to skip the first big sentence (Description) on the
  Jquery Docs =)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's easy to look at the documentation before asking http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: You could have written a 3 line script to test this.

Comment: @Archer How you can test this in 3 lines?

Comment: @Azd325 1. `for (var i = 0, len = id.length, i < len; i++) {` 2. `console.log(id[i].value);` 3. `}`. Running a loop to iterate over the indexes of your array will output all the values, then you can check what you get from the loop against `id.val()`

Comment: @Azd325 http://jsfiddle.net/VN98u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` will check the value of the first element in the set of elements it is run on. If you pass `.val()` a function like this: `.val(function (index, value) {})` then you can get the value for every element in the set of element that the function is run on.

You might want to check-out the docs for `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val

```
$('input').val(function () {
    console.log(this.value);
    return this.value;
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mV4U6/2/ (If you change the value of any input then the value of all the inputs will be `console.log`ed)

As lonesomeday stated, this requires you to return the value so the form element will retain its value. You can however use `.map()` to get the values of each input:

```
$('input').map(function (index, element) {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Here is a demo using `.map()`: http://jsfiddle.net/mV4U6/3/

...Also possible with a loop:

```
var $inputs = $('input');
for (var i = 0, len = $inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log($inputs[i][0].value);//or inputs[i].val() will also work
}
```

Comment: The `val` function syntax is for setting, not for getting. If you want to get all the values, you should probably use `map` rather than `val`.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks, that's a good observation. Either return the value of the input while using `.val()` or just use `.map()` or `.each()`.

Comment: Using `val` is definitely the harder way. [Here's an example of the best way to use `map`](http://jsfiddle.net/mV4U6/5/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the values use map function

```
var ids = id.map(function(index, element){
   return $(this).val();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, `.val()`, as well as all other getter methods, return the value of the first selected element.

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1

http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` returns the value of the first element which matches the selector.

Additionally, IDs must be unique, so you have to choose another **unique** ID, or replace `id` with `class`. Another option is to drop the `id` attribute and select by name: `$('[name="id"]')`.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery source:

```
val: function( value ) {
    var hooks, ret, isFunction,
        elem = this[0];
```

[(Line 161 of src/attributes.js)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L161)

The element that is tested with `val` is always `[0]`, the first one in the set, no matter how many there are or what the values are.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> val() = Get the current value of the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

So it only works on the first element that's matched by the selector.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a jQuery collection of elements, `.val()` will only return the first value.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the value for only the first one.
http://api.jquery.com/val/